# keyboard shortcut to paste frequently used email addresses or passwords in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

Is there a way to use a keyboard shortcut to quickly paste frequently used addresses without them being on the clipboard? For example, I don't like to stay logged into Facebook, so when I go onto Facebook I usually will need to login. Can I set up a keyboard shortcut that will paste my login info. Obviously I would need to set up several different key combinations for maybe 5 frequently used logons. How can I do this in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2):

For general typing/hotkey functionality, use Typinator, TypeIt4Me, TextExpander, Butler by Manytricks, or Keyboard Maestro.

You can also use AppleScript and/or Automator to write these simple scripts yourself.

To store web site login information, use your browser's password storage (likely via OS X Keychain, or specific to the browser), or 1Password.

The integrated text substitution in OS X (*System Preferences » Language & Text » Text*) does not seem to work with browser input fields.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend 1Password. Been using it for years. It's awesome! 
Check out the keyboard shortcuts it has :)
https://blog.agilebits.com/2014/07/28/1password-keyboard-shortcuts/

But the Mac can do this with the safari settings as well. Safari will store it's data in the keychain in an encrypted state.

I don't recommend text expander or similar types of software for this use case! It's not encrypted. Not good for passwords.